# Standard Deviation of One Variable Weighted By Second Variable

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation, variance, weighted

I would like to calculate standard deviation of a variable that weighs each observation by a second variable.

```
values <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 200)
sizes <- c(12, 54, 1, 218, 63)
```

How do I find the standard deviation of `values` with weighting applied based on `sizes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Hmisc` is rather large. In the time it took me to install and load that package, which has multiple dependencies, I did this using base R. First, I had to check the formula from Wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean:

[image]

Note that V1 is just the sum of the weights. Then I just converted that into R-speak:

```
x <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 200)
w <- c(12, 54, 1, 218, 63)
mu <- weighted.mean(x, w)

sqrt(sum(w * ((x-mu)^2))/(sum(w) - 1))
[1] 102.696
```

Which agrees with the `wtd.var` function from `Hmisc`.

Of course, if you want added functionality, like normalisation, maximum likelihood estimation, or removing NA for you, then go with the `wtd.var` function. But the OP didn't specify any of that. Also, if your internet speed is slow, or you want to try to do things yourself and learn at the same time, then use my method. :)

**Edit 1**: And for *reliability* weights (`normwt=TRUE`):

```
> V1 <- sum(w)
> V2 <- sum(w^2)
> sqrt(sum(w * ((x-mw)^2))/(V1 - V2/V1))
[1] 138.3356
```

**Edit 2**: Handling missing values (`na.rm=TRUE`):

```
obs <- !is.na(x) & !is.na(w)
x <- x[obs]
w <- w[obs]
```

Then use these instead.

Comment: I should have clarified that I was looking for a base R solution, and yours works perfectly.  How would you modify it to allow an `na.rm = TRUE` option?

Comment: Remove them, including any in the weights vector. See my second Edit. Or write your own function, or use the function from the Hmisc package. Note that the data and the weights must have the same length.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `wtd.var` from `Hmisc` to get the variance and then take the square root of it

```
sqrt(Hmisc::wtd.var(values, sizes))
#[1] 102.696
```

As @AaronMontgomery mentioned, the `normwt = TRUE` may be needed to make the weights sum to the length of 'values' after deletion of NAs (By default, it is FALSE)

```
sqrt(Hmisc::wtd.var(values, sizes, normwt = TRUE))
#[1] 138.3356v
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong -- I think you may also want `normwt = TRUE`  supplied into `wtd.var()`. If this isn't specified, then `wtd.var()` treats the variance as though the counts are repeats (i.e. n = `sum(sizes)` = 348`) instead of n = 5, which gives a different numerical result. (See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-June/133156.html)

Comment: I was probably too hasty to suggest using `normwt = TRUE`, actually. I think it's not clear from Jason's post whether that should be used or not. Here's a good explanation of the difference between them; formula (A) in the link is `normwt = FALSE`, and formula (C) is `normwt = TRUE`. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61641/216364 The upshot is that the question can't be answered without specifying what the weights *are*.